# Understanding (missunderstanding?) prototype based classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, firefox, browser, prototype

I'm trying to understand how prototype class system works in JS. So far I'm little bit confused about the results I've got after creating and displaying objects (in Firefox).
When I create an object using 'Example 1' I got an object who's prototype has one property (speak function) and who has an instance property 'type'. And this behavior is clear.
But in the second example, using keyword 'new' I got an object with an instance property 'type' and a prototype who has a constructor itself (Rabbit) and defined function 'speak'. And this function 'speak' has non empty 'prototype' property and this relation going further etc. Same with prototype constructor. His constructor has 'prototype' property holding the same content as previous level and etc.
And this behavior seems like an infinite recursion tree. I do not understand if this behavior is normal language "feature"?

```
// Example 1
let protoRabbit = {
    speak(line) {
    console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}'`);
    }
};
function makeRabbit(type) {
    let rabbit = Object.create(protoRabbit);
    rabbit.type = type;
    return rabbit;
}
// Example 2
function Rabbit(type) {
    this.type = type;
}
Rabbit.prototype.speak = function(line) {
    console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}'`);
};
let weirdRabbit = new Rabbit("weird");
console.log(weirdRabbit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not actually 'infinite' even if it seems like it. The prototype's constructor of the (Rabbit) object refers back to itself, so as you go deeper, you are just opening the same (Rabbit) object over and over again.

Comment: I thought about that. But then, why constructor's prototype (should be an empty Object type) has it's own constructor who's pointing back to itself?

Comment: Never mind. I understood why it points to itself (because prototype object is being property of constructor, so it should indicate somehow). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor prototype is implicitly back to itself so that other children has access to the parent through "[[prototype]]" object. We can use constructor property to create a new object using the same constructor as the existing one.

You can find a detailed knowledge on this from the below site.

https://javascript.info/function-prototype